# paper autocomplete in not showing any results

Tags: javascript, polymer-3.x

I have been trying to use paper-autocomplete to get auto suggestions for an input field. I'm using Polymer 3.0

I'm getting auto suggestion drop down when I type something in the input field, but it is showing as empty.

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from "./node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js";
import './node_modules/@fluidnext-polymer/paper-autocomplete/paper-autocomplete.js';

class MyBot extends PolymerElement {
   static get template()
   {
       return html`
           <paper-autocomplete label="Search Something" source={{array}}> 
           </paper-autocomplete>

           <iron-ajax
        auto
        id= "getSuggestions"
                url=""
                handle-as="json"
                on-response="autosuggest"
                debounce-duration="300">
       </iron-ajax>
    `;
   }

   static get properties()
   {

   };

   autosuggest(responses)
   {
       console.log('questions');
       let rows = responses.detail.response; //console.log(rows);
       let result=[]; 
       for(var i in rows)
       result.push( rows [i]['question']);
       this.array=result;
    }

}
```

I'm getting these errors

1. Could not find style data in module named paper-material-styles style-gather.js:82

2.the autosuggestion drop down is not showing any data. (Sorry I could't post photo because of less reputation)

Got the suggestions by using

```
<paper-autocomplete label="Search Something" source={{array}}  text-property="key"> </paper-autocomplete>
```

where key is the key in the array

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'array' to your properties object.
And maybe rename 'array' to a more logical name like searchList

```
static get properties()
   {
       searchList: Array
   };
```

A good way to see if your variable gets updated is opening your element inspector, then select the outer element:  in the dom-inspector and type $0.searchList in your terminal to see the variable value. Where 'searchList' is your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to observable changes in object or array use;

```
autosuggest(responses) {
       ...
       this.set('array', result); // instead of this.array=result;
}
```

Here the related link for [more information](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/model-data):

Comment: The search list is getting filled with the results. But they are not visible in auto suggestion drop down.

Comment: @SaitejaPamulapati , I made a working example here at the link. I found out that you need to use `text-property="..."` option if your array is object array. https://stackblitz.com/edit/polymer3-paper-autocomplete-in-not-showing-any-results?file=index.js

Comment: got it by using text-property="..."